# How to pick an inductor for the LM2576 when not using the recommended options from the datasheet?

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, inductor, switching-regulator

I am selecting an inductor for the [LM2576HVT-15.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2576hv.pdf?ts=1691061674665&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FLM2576HV%252Fpart-details%252FLM2576HVT-12%252FNOPB%253Futm_source%253Dgoogle%2526utm_medium%253Dcpc%2526utm_campaign%253Docb-tistore-promo-app_opn_en-cpc-storeic-google-wwe%2526utm_content%253DDevice%2526ds_k%253DLM2576HVT-12%252FNOPB%2526DCM%253Dyes%2526gclid%253DCj0KCQjwoK2mBhDzARIsADGbjeq96vi_mp8yl-ektAkuWlFH85ajhwfm80YI7sd3WGFP49nZFiEHmkcaAmKyEALw_wcB%2526gclsrc%253Daw.ds) The datasheet has some recommendations, but the only recommended options are inductors that and relatively big and have exposed wires. I do not want a package that has exposed wires and is big so I am left to selecting an alternate inductor by myself (not to mention it is out of stock).

My application will use less then 0.5A and it has an input voltage of about 42V, so the inductor that the datasheet recommends for my application will be the [PE-53121NL](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/pulse-electronics/PE-53121NL/2266088?s=N4IgTCBcDaIAoFEC0BWAzARjBkBdAvkA).

Obviously the inductance value match the recommended inductance of 1.5 mH, current rating and voltage rating have to be higher then my application current and voltage, but how important are the rest of the characteristics? The PE-53121NL doesn't have a self resonant frequency or a Q value listed (not sure if this means there is no value or the manufacturer just didn't include them)? Does inductor Type matter (Recommended part has type "Toroidal")? How do I select an appropriate alternate inductor?

Comment: There's a very good chance that if you find a significantly smaller inductor it will be inadequate in terms of saturation current, which will cause serious problems.

Comment: Please simulate it. What peak current did you get at worst case scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The PE-53121NL appears to use a mix #26 powdered iron core, judging by the Digikey photo of it.  This is only half as good a resistor as it is an inductor -- it's a very low quality material, as in quality factor: typically Q is 5-10 at 50kHz.

Any part with comparable L and DCR will do, and any other part's core losses will almost certainly outperform this one.  A closed style (shielded) ferrite or composite type inductor would seem to suit your request.

SRF is generally not important, with typical parts generally being high enough not to care.

Generally, SRF will be several times larger than Fsw, but what's really important is the second self-resonant frequency (which has a low impedance characteristic).  Unfortunately, it is rarely if ever documented for parts.  The SRF normally reported (if they do at all!) is actually the maximum impedance point for the component -- which is good for a switching converter, that means current flow at those frequencies is minimal, it's the best filtering it can give you.  You may at least guess that the 2nd resonance is not far above (say 2-3 times), which does tend to encourage a somewhat higher SRF (say >10 times Fsw).  But without measurements or an impedance vs. frequency curve, these are just guesses.

---

I would also recommend against using a 3A regulator, with maximum limit up to 7.5A, for a 0.5A application.  At least without fusing to protect the inductor in case of output short-circuit.  Let alone the effect of inductor saturation, which may cause unexpected behavior with the control loop.

Significant size savings, and likely cost as well, can be had with a modern regulator type (notice the initial date 1999 for the LM2576 datasheet, it's a very old model!).  Offhand, I might reach for a LMR12007XMK, MP2456GJ or similar part.  Perhaps even an NCP3063.

(Case in point: LM2576 is from the days when MC34063 and similar hysteretic and voltage-mode controllers/regulators were popular: back when cost-per-transistor on the IC was still noticeable, and before the benefits of better control schemes (like peak current mode control) were well appreciated.  Likewise, processes were too slow to significantly reduce component size, and component quality still had some development to go.  Nowadays, ICs are tiny and fast, with rich control and protection features; and lower-loss inductors, and low-ESR electrolytics and large-value ceramics, are the norm, cheap and affordable.)

(Case slightly out of point: NCP3063 is basically an improved MC34063.  It's far from perfect, but it is at least improved in several important ways (faster, lower saturation, improved control), and its flexibility might prove attractive if one has a component-reuse concern in a design.)

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail on selecting an inductor based on self resonant frequency and selecting a suitable inductor? There are a lot of inductors that I am seeing that don't have a self resonant frequency or a Q value listed, but it does have an "inductance frequency - test" value. Sometimes they don't have any of this listed or all of it listed. What does all this mean? How can I be sure I am selecting a suitable inductor?

Comment: It only means: if they don't tell you, you don't know.

Comment: Pick an inductor not based on output current but on the max current the IC can produce.   (current limit value)  I see your load is 0.5A but during startup the current will be much higher.